# How to use "A secure, local entropy source for random number generation" in offchain worker?

Tags: offchain-worker, random

The official website tells us there is " [A secure, local entropy source for random number generation](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/offchain-operations/)" . I think it means that I can make use of this feature to generate random number or even  generate key pair in offchain worker. I want to know how to implement this.Is there any code snippet that I could learn?

Answer (score 1):

For offchain workers there is the [`random_seed`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a357c29ebabb075235977edd5e3901c66575f995/primitives/io/src/lib.rs#L1208) function. This will return you a random seed that you can use to initialize a random number generator.

Comment: Sorry , I am a green hand and I don't have much experience. Can you tell me which crate should I import into my code?

Comment: You could use [`ChaCha20Rng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_chacha/struct.ChaCha20Rng.html).

`ChaCha20Rng::from_seed(sp_io::offchain::random_seed()).next_u32()`.